# MapPageRoute on iis7 not working (but works in iis6)

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, migration

My WebSite runs fine on iis6, as you can see here: http://93.115.250.xxx/

I recently tried to migrate it to iis7, and after a lot of hussle I now can see the starting page, but all urls rewritten through mappageroute give a 404 as you can see here: 94.75.xxx.xxx

Any ideas as to why iis7 is trying to access a physical file and ignores the pageroute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently programming in a mixed environment. My alpha server is Server2008, beta and production are still 2003. You need to modify the config file to have system.webServer node with the following entry:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

I am not sure if this is applicable in your instance, but my application required log-in accept for publicly available image files available from a re-written directory. Don't forget to add an except to where the route is mapped:

```
   <location path="{target path}">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I figured this out a long time ago, and it is also needed to add the specific module for some IIS installations like so:
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

Comment: I think that referencing the UrlRoutingModule is only necessary if you are working in a legacy 3.5 application though, right? I mean, I run a .NET 4 web application on a Server 2003/2008 instance and that is not required to use routing. Well, good luck!